# How can I create an entity with multi values?

Tags: mysql

I wanto to implement the following in MySql but I'm still confused.I want to create a table student with these arguments:Name,Surname,Semester,Courses,Phones(one or more)
How can I insert one or more phones?(For example a student may have one or more cellphone numbers or one or more home numbers or both)

By far I have written this:

```
CREATE TABLE student(Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,Surname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Semester INT NOT NULL,Courses varchar(255) );
```

--I don't know how to write multi values(Phone ) for the entity of student

Comment: You should read about one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for a student to have a one to many relationship on phone numbers.

For example, a student would have only one surname and so this is a one to one to relationship. Whereas they could have multiple phone numbers so this is a one to many relationship.

Generally the best way to store a one to many relationship is by storing phone numbers in a different table, called phonenumbers perhaps. Each phone number should be a new row in the phonenumbers table.  To allow the information to be linked between your two tables, you would need a field in your phonenumbers table called student_id (or similar) that stores the id of the student that that phone number belongs to.

To join the multiple phone numbers to your single student when retrieving this information from the database you would need to use a join statement between your student table and the phonenumbers table in your SQL query.

Comment: So is it a good solution to create two tables and then join them?...Do I also  need to find their primary and foreign keys before joining them?

Comment: You will want to have a primary key for your student table. I would suggest a field called student_id for this. You will then want a foreign key in your phonenumbers table, maybe also called student_id, which will reference the student_id for who that phone number relates to.

Comment: To actually join the tables, you do not need to find the keys first and then execute a new query to join them. It can all be done in one query using a join statement. If you have not come across joins before then a quick google will provide plenty of examples for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add different rows for phones, like Home_phone and Personal_phone like this

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `Name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Semester` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Courses` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Personal Phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Home Phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: If I do this it would be a mistake (a design mistake in my db),because think that a student might have two personal phones,two home phones

Comment: than add Personal Phone1 , Personal Phone2 , Home Phone1 and Home Phone 2... if not, as is said below, make another table with phones, and u can add as many phones u want.
For that you will need an ID before 'Name' and another ID at Phones table with reference at your studedents table and just simply (select s.name,p.persphone1,p.persphone2 ...etc.... where s.id=p.id )